# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, hbase

I have gone through all the answers related to similar questions, but I was unable to come to a conclusion about the issue being in my Java code or Hbase configuration. So I am posting this question again. I am getting bellow error in Hbase. I have 3 VMs for Hadoop cluster.

**Master node - 3 GB RAM**

**Datanode 1 - 7 GB RAM**

**Datanode 2 - 7 GB RAM**

My Java program is running on Hbase Master Node, this worker insert data into the Hbase table and approximately after inserting 100k records I got below error and both the Java program and HMaster stopped working.

***Java Program Error :-***

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x00007fe05185c000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot
>   allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to
>   continue. Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 12288
>   bytes for committing reserved memory.
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> /var/data/HadoopOperations/javaOperations/hs_err_pid41813.log

Log for **hs_err_pid41813.log**

> processor : 1
>
> vendor_id : AuthenticAMD
>
> cpu family   : 16
>
> model     : 8
>
> model name    : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE
>
> stepping  : 1
>
> microcode : 0xffffffff
>
> cpu MHz       : 2094.643
>
> cache size    : 512 KB
>
> physical id   : 0
>
> siblings  : 2
>
> core id       : 1
>
> cpu cores : 2
>
> apicid        : 1
>
> initial apicid    : 1
>
> fpu       : yes
>
> fpu_exception : yes
>
> cpuid level   : 5
>
> wp        : yes
>
> flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
>   pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt lm
>   3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 popcnt hypervisor
>   lahf_lm cmp_legacy cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw
>   vmmcall
>
> bugs     : tlb_mmatch apic_c1e fxsave_leak
>
> bogomips : 4205.20
>
> TLB size  : 1024 4K pages
>
> clflush size  : 64
>
> cache_alignment   : 64
>
> address sizes : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual power management:
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 3523172k(135048k free), swap 0k(0k free)
>
> vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE
>   (1.7.0_79-b14), built on Jul 24 2015 08:15:54 by "buildd" with gcc
>   4.8.2
>
> time: Fri Sep  4 06:43:48 2015
>
> elapsed time: 63099 seconds

**hbase-site.xml configuration**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
            <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
    </property> 

    <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
            <value>2181</value> 
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name><value>master,datanodeone,datanodetwo</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
            <value>10000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>hfile.block.cache.size</name>
            <value>0.6</value> 
    </property> 

    <property>
            <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size</name>
            <value>0.2</value> 
    </property>         
 </configuration>
```

Comment: What is the heap size allocated for Hbase Master

Comment: heap size is to default for hbase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have almost no free memory and no swap.

```
physical 3523172k(135048k free), swap 0k(0k free)
```

The simplest solution is to add some swap space, I suggest 4 GB minimum, up to 16 GB.

Comment: i had not close the htable object in my java program, Is that a reason for memory issue?

Comment: It might make a difference, but the key problem is you ran out of virtual memory (and indeed physical memory)  This might be the solution for now, but if you got this close to the limit, I would seriously consider adding some swap space.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Swap file of 2G

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=2048 bs=1MiB
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

add this line:
`/swapfile   swap    swap    sw  0   0`

run `swapon --show` and `free -h` to verify